# Best philosophy of mathematics (text)book?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, reference-request

What work (or works) are best for beginning an independent study of the philosophy of  mathematics?

Comment: "Best" is a subjective term... there seems to be some obvious hits using google, have you tried that? Do you have some particular thing your looking for (history of philosophy of mathematics? modern understanding of the philosophy of mathematics? How mathematics relates to other subjects?) Giving more context would be helpful.

Comment: Steward Shapiro, "Thinking about Mathematics" (2000)

Answer (score 6):

Some historical :

- Morris Kline, [Mathematics: The Loss of Certainty](https://books.google.it/books?id=RNwnUL33epsC&printsec=frontcover), 1980
- Marcus Giaquinto, [The Search for Certainty : A Philosophical Account of Foundations of Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=gyNbrpYXzxoC&printsec=frontcover), 2002.

Some anthologies, like :

- Stewart Shapiro (editor), [The Oxford Handbook of Philosophy of Mathematics and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=hPztJzVE8j0C&printsec=frontcover), 2005.

Very useful also the articles in *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy* (with bibliography) starting with [Philosophy of Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/).